# Importing .vue template globally with a custom tagname

Tags: vue.js

I wants to name my `.vue` file as `Application.vue`, for instance, but using the tagname `my-application`.

With `Vue.component()` I can just call like `Vue.component('my-application')`, but as I am importing my component with template (from `import`), then I can't name it.

I wants that this component be registered globally on my application element (from `new Vue()`), then I like to use that inner any element inside my application element.

---

**My current code is something like:**

```
import "vue/Application.vue";
new Vue({ el: appNode});
```

**Component:**

```
<template>
    <div>Test</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put your import in a variable (by using `import x from 'x'`), and then you can use `Vue.component(name, component)` to register the component:

```
import Application from 'vue/Application.vue'
Vue.component('my-application', Application')
```

Then, in the Component where you want to use it

```
<template>
  <my-application>Test</my-application>
</template>
```

Comment: Great! How could I not think of that? I just replaced the import to require.
`Vue.component('my-application', require('...'))`

Comment: @DavidRodrigues So … time to mark this answer as correct? :)

Comment: Yeah, I did! SO have a limitation to accept an answer fastly.

Comment: Oops, sorry. :D